# Linux gedit and the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, gedit

Whenever I am using gedit to write code I can access either gedit or the terminal but not both. For example, when I type gedit hello.c linux brings up the file hello.c inside gedit. Now, while gedit is still displaying hello.c I cannot type anything into the terminal without closing hello.c in gedit.

How can I get around this so that I may actively use both the terminal and gedit simultaneously?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

type `gedit hello.c &`

or if you have already typed it without the ampersand press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to send it to background, and type `bg` to enable gedit as David pointed out.

Comment: Ctrl + Z will only stop the job. You need to call `bg` when back at the prompt so that the job is backgrounded.

Answer (score 1):

if you already started gedit, press CTRL + Z, then type

```
bg && disown
```

dis will run gedit in background and disown it from the terminal (so gedit wont die if you close the terminal)